# How to Launch UWP Application without splash screen or UI

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am in a condition where I want to launch UWP app without showing window  or splash screen.

It has to be silent running process.

Comment: I have been through so many articles which says no it is not possible. So, thought if anyboyd has come across same scenario and have found any workaround or any other way

Comment: mention the most usefull articles or things that you have tried.

Comment: A background task process? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task

Comment: have you checked this - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/27a3e5f8-87f6-428f-bb7a-8f5126d94d7f/running-uwp-app-with-no-ui?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: What is the purpose of this application?

Comment: the purpose of this application to show toast notification to action center. However, this is central application and it gets toast message from other .exe(windows service) which are running always. User may close this app but services or any other components want to show toast.  By design, we want to handle the toast notification  from all other other components. Component communication is using our internal framework.

Comment: We can't launch uwp app without showing window or splash screen. You could try to use win32 or wpf app to achieve it.